# Is it possible to download a pdf from a authenticated session in wkwebview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

This question was asked before. But my requirement is different. I have a workflow like this

1. User login to app using WKWebView()
2. User has an invoice tab after logging in through which he can download invoices by clicking a button.
3. The issue arises here. While desktop and android apps are able to download pdf , In iOS it's not downloading. I tried many workarounds like "decidePolicyFor", download pdf once its URL is known etc.
4. The problem which I think is normal pdf files which needed to be downloaded usually has a ".pdf" at the end of its URL.. ex- "www.xyz.com/books.pdf", However mine is like this - "www.xyz.com/library/id=10"
5. It may be also because the server give access to pdf only if it is authenticated. which is not the case if I try to download using URL directly

Any help will be appreciated

My CodeBase till now

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class WebKitViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    var pdfUrl:URL!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setViewContext()
    }

    func setViewContext()  {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com")!
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

    func downloadPDF(fromUrl url:String)  {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }

               let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())

               let downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: url)
               downloadTask.resume()

    }
    @IBAction func openPDFButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let pdfViewController = PDFViewController()
        pdfViewController.pdfURL = self.pdfUrl
        present(pdfViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }}
extension WebKitViewController:WKNavigationDelegate{
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let host = navigationAction.request.url {
            if host.absoluteString.contains("https://www.example.com/en/my-account/invoicePDF/"){
                 decisionHandler(.cancel)
                print(host.absoluteString)
                self.downloadPDF(fromUrl: host.absoluteString)
                return
            }
           }
           decisionHandler(.allow)

    }
}


extension WebKitViewController:  URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        print("downloadLocation:", location)
        do {
            let documentsURL = try
                FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                        in: .userDomainMask,
                                        appropriateFor: nil,
                                        create: false)

            let savedURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("yourCustomName90.pdf")
            self.pdfUrl = savedURL
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: savedURL)

        } catch {
            print ("file error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Note - The pdf downloads in macOS safari

Comment: As far as I can tell, your `downloadTask ` is not authenticated. Implement the `URLSession ` delegates, you should get some more information from them

Comment: Use your own server get response after login, rather as a session key or whatever to know the user is logged in, then as a second security check with server from your pdf url appending the session key so only that user can access the file. It does not matter if key changes all the time on login (this is a good practice) so this is a simple way to implement for your task. The url may look like host/useraccount/invoicePdf&securekey=....other method is to send custom key in headers for download requests.

Comment: You cant download the PDF on your iPhone by going to a URL but you can make it appear in a browser style page

Comment: @Saamer not true, he can download any kind of file if he reach the URL. Simple with any network request manager, as for example Alamofire  public static func download(_ url: URLConvertible,
                                method: HTTPMethod = .get,
                                parameters: Parameters? = nil,
                                encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
                                headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil,
                                interceptor: RequestInterceptor? = nil,
                                to destination:...

Comment: Hmm I don’t think I worded it correctly. I meant to say that unlike Android and web, it won’t automatically download a file by clicking a link

Answer (score 3):

Try to read cookies from webview and save it before making a call to download your pdf:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    self.webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { cookies in
       //save cookies
       self.cookies = cookies
    }
}


func downloadPDF(fromUrl url:String)  {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(cookies, for: url, mainDocumentURL:nil)
    ...
}
```